# Upgrade\Migrate Apache Hadoop 1.x to Apache Hadoop 2.x

Tags: apache, hadoop

I am looking into migrating\upgrading from Apache Hadoop 1.x to Apache Hadoop 2.x.

I didn’t find any doc\guide\blogs for the same.

Although there are guides\docs for the CDH and HDP migration\upgradation from Hadoop 1.x to Hadoop 2.x

Would referring those be of some use?

I am looking for similar guides\docs for Apache Hadoop 1.x to Apache Hadoop 2.x.

I found something on slideshare though. Not sure how much useful that is going to be. I still need to verify that.
http://www.slideshare.net/mikejf12/an-example-apache-hadoop-yarn-upgrade

Any suggestions\comments will be of great help.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's an official document: http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduce_Compatibility_Hadoop1_Hadoop2.html

Also you can check on [slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/tshooter/strata-conf2014) one on the topic.

This is an answer made of links, but I don't see the point to replicate the information here, as you can't migrate but some simple procedure.